# remove cancel button in appcelerator search

Tags: ios, appcelerator, searchbar

I am trying to create a search bar for iOS.By default what i get is : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.SearchBar . Is there a way to disable to cancel button since i alreay get a (small cross) to cancel the search ?? Also can we reduce the width of search bar,and move the hintText to left side??
Application type: Mobile Titanium SDK:4.0.GA Platform & version:iOS 8 xcode 6 Device :iPad Host OS:iOS
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To hide cancel button refer this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.SearchBar-property-showCancel

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make manual search bar if you need more tweaking as native objects not always support more options to modify them.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not access to write comments on main question. I can only write comments on my answer. :)